# Allow single ingress to run HTTP without forcing SSL using Traefik Ingress Controller

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I have Traefik set as my Ingress controller via the [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/traefik) on version 1.5.4. I have LetsEncrypt enabled and SSL set to Enforced so all of my exposed services are forcing SSL as desired.

I have recently run into a situation where I need to *not* force SSL on a single ingress. I have tried every annotation I could find but the most I can get to happen is a redirect loop (http -> https -> http) leading me to believe that SSL is still enforced.

Has anyone managed to get this running via annotations? [Here](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/backends/kubernetes/) are the annotations for 1.5 Thanks!

My currently deployed Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-09-18T05:52:41Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: prerender
    chart: prerender-0.4.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: prerender
  name: prerender-prerender
  namespace: production-prerender-io
  resourceVersion: "41421557"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/production-prerender-io/ingresses/prerender-prerender
  uid: 0e8a1286-bb07-11e8-9938-06e82a01885c
spec:
  rules:
  - host: prerender.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: prerender-prerender
          servicePort: 3000
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) on a single `Ingress`. In other words, once you go TLS on an Ingress you can't go back. Ingress as in this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: mytlssecret
  backend:
    serviceName: service1
    servicePort: 80
```

It would be nice to have something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: mytlssecret
  backend:
    serviceName: service1
    servicePort: 80
    tlsFrontend: false
```

Created [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68944) to see if it can happen. The workaround I guess is creating another Ingress.

Edit:

The Traefik helm chart configures Traefik specifically with letsencrypt so in this case the non-TLS backend would have to be supported specifically by Traefik through a backend annotation.

Comment: So my actual ingress rule doesn't have TLS set, it's a global Traefik option. Attaching my current ingress created via Helm for Prerender.io

https://pastebin.com/8qFY5Uxf

Comment: How are serving https then?

Comment: I am using ACME (letsencrypt) with Traefik as the Ingress Controller, so every Ingress automatically gets an LE cert generated/renewed. You can check the Helm chart for Traefik to see what the "enforced" option does here on line 40 https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/traefik/templates/configmap.yaml

Comment: I guess in this case it needs to be supported by Traefik itself through an annotation as you had originally suggested.

Comment: Btw, another option to use letsencrypt with Traefik is to use the [Certificate Manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager)